# Set-Cookie then Redirect with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, setcookie

I'm moving a site over from one domain to another. I'd like to detect the referer and to offer an explanation on the new site (e.g. Company X has changed its name to company Y), which I'm doing on searches, but after a 301 redirect the `HTTP_REFERER` is blank so I thought of setting a cookie with a short lifespan then redirecting. On the new site check if the cookie exists and show the message.

This is what I've come up with:

```
Header set Set-Cookie "oldsiteredirect=true"
Redirect 301 / http://newsite.com/
```

The redirect is working fine but no cookie is set. And I'd also like to set the expires as now + 10 seconds.

Is this the way to go or is there a simpler solution out there?

Thanks.

Comment: It is not possible to set a cookie on one domain, then read it on another without some trickery.

Comment: Try setting up cookie for target domain (instead of current domain) straight away. Maybe you will need to use `RewriteRule` (mod_rewrite) instead of `Redirect` to do redirect and cookie at the same time (look at `CO` flag: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_co).

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the new site to "know" that there was a redirect, why don't you use a parameter?

> Redirect 301 / `http://newsite.com/?oldsiteredirect=true`